# How do I base an If statement off the user's input decimal points?

Tags: c++, double

So, I've searched on this forum and people seem to be understanding a basic concept that I just don't - so I apologize if this seems simple. I'm on my third week of my first C++ class, and this is the problem.

"The user will provide a numerical value to your program. If the number contains any decimal values greater than 0, print out the word "double". Otherwise, print the word "int"."

I get if statements, and the syntax needed for this - I just don't get how I can focus my condition solely on the decimal points.

So I can have an input like 3.4, and print double. Input 3, and print int.

Comment: What language are you programming in? The typical way to do this is to subtract the integer value from the double and check for a remainder (pseudo-code): `if ((double)value - (int)value != 0.0)` you have decimals.

Comment: What "syntax" is needed--syntax of an `if` statement, syntax of the input, or of something else? It might help to see your best (although unsuccessful) attempt, to help infer what's missing.

Comment: C++ - Ken White's answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double value;
    cin >> value;
    int integ = value;
    if (value - integ == 0.0 )
    {
        cout << "int";
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "double";
    }
     return 0;
}
```

the above should do it.